# Hide fake score on Google Play Service Leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I released my Android game a few days ago, and I just noticed a fake score on the leaderboard.

I heard it was possible to hide these manually, with players.hide() : https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide, but I can't find a way to get the required player ID.

Does anyone know how to get that ? Or if there is another way to hide fake scores ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: To answer the players question: have you tried getting the leaderboard? So the response for this call https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/leaderboards/get should probably contain the ID's

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the score of a specific player using the REST management API.

[See the documentation of the call to see how it can be done](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide). Sadly there's no GUI for doing this.